# Seaboron : subplot: TypeError: tuple indices must be integers or slices, not tuple

Tags: python-3.x, seaborn, subplot

Getting Below error when using seaborn countplot along with subplot

TypeError: tuple indices must be integers or slices, not tuple

Answer (score 1):

Reason might be missing fig variable on return.

For example, taking the same sample that was provided by Robbie [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43131274/how-do-i-plot-two-countplot-graphs-side-by-side-in-seaborn)

Reason for me was that I had missed to use "fig" variable for return in subplot, somehow I am not able to recreate the scenario.  I was doing as below

```
ax =plt.subplots(1,2)
```

when the above statement was rewritten as below, it then worked.

```
fig, ax =plt.subplots(1,2)
```